# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to remove the splash image?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I want to remove the IBM splash image when the app launches. How do I accomplish this in the Android environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From which environment...?
What is your Worklight version?

- In **iOS** you cannot not-have a splash image
- In **Android** you will need to delete the `splash.9.png` image file from `your-project\apps\your-app\native\res\drawable`
- In other environments you will need to find and delete the splash image file from the envrionment's native resources

Comment: I am using Worklight 6 and i want to create Android environment.

Comment: Then you have your answer above re: how to remove the splash image from the Android environment.